# python- How can I get value passed to class decorators?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a class decorator that have two arguments as following:

```
def decoratorB(x: int, y: int): 
    def inner(cls):
        def no_wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            return cls(*args, **kwargs)

        no_wrap.x = x
        no_wrap.y = y
        return no_wrap

    return inner
```

and I used it to decorate a class in this way:

```
@decoratorB(x=100, y=-100)
class ClassB():
    def func(self, name):
        pass
```

How can I get the values of x and y from an object of `ClassB`?

```
obj = ClassB()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do realize you are replacing your class with a function, right? `ClassB` becomes another name for  the function `no_wrap`, so `x` and `y` are accessible as `ClassB.x` and `ClassB.y`. `obj` is an instance of the original class, as returned by the *function* `ClassB`, and contains no references to `x` or `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try printing the dir of `ClassB` vs `obj`.

```py
>>> print(dir(obj))
# ['__class__', ..., 'func']

>>> print(dir(ClassB))
# ['__annotations__', ..., 'x', 'y']
```

Notice how `x` and `y` are only found in ClassB as a class, not as an instance of it. Also notice how `func` is only found in the instance. This is because of how you defined the decorator. We are applying the attributes to `no_wrap` instead of the obj itself.
You can either manually set the attributes in `__init__` or change the decorator.

```py
@decoratorB(x=100, y=-100)
class ClassB:
    def __init__(self):
        for attr in dir(ClassB)[35:]: # Get rid of builtin methods so we don't override
            setattr(self, attr, getattr(ClassB, attr, None))
    def func(self, name):
        pass

>>> print(dir(Class())
# ['__class__', ..., 'func', 'x', 'y']
```

**Edit:** Thanks to chepner's comment up there, I realized we could just rewrite the decorator instead.

We should take the cls object and assign the values to the object instead of a "copy".

```py
def decoratorB(x: int, y: int): 
    def inner(cls):
        new = cls
        new.x = x
        new.y = y
        return new
    return inner

>>> print(dir(ClassB))
# ['__class__', 'func', 'x', 'y']

>>> print(dir(ClassB()))
# ['__class__', 'func', 'x', 'y']
```